# MVC for our application?

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc

There are some issues about how to manage our program designs and programming styles. I was assigned to find a solution to write reusable code - though, the programming team does not follow the rules.

I would rather use MVC to perform a well structured programming style. I found out that a blueprint for next works requires a bunch of experts. The thing is that I have to do it all myself. And the worse part is that I have to use a general MVC platform.

I need your helps and suggestions for:

1. Is there a way that I can write a document for MVC - to use it in our design in Java?
2. How can I represent it?
3. How much work does it need?
4. How can I connect the Model, the View, and the controller parts together?

Answer (score 7):

- MVC is just a design pattern - it's not a silver bullet.
- Ask yourself:  Are you actually designing a UI?
- There are lots of MVC frameworks out there, don't re-invent the wheel!
- UML is typically used to represent the MVC structure - there's a million generic diagrams out there already